# How to turn multiples promises dependent on each other's response into await and make sure all requests fire

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I have an array of objects that has 3 items inside it. I'm iterating over it and during each loop i need to make 3 API calls that all depend on each other's response. So in total there should be 9 API requests completed.

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    first: 'thing',
    second: 'thing',
    third: 'thing'
  },
  {
    fourth: 'thing',
    fifth: 'thing',
    sixth: 'thing'
  },
  {
    seventh: 'thing',
    eight: 'thing',
    ninth: 'thing'
  },
]
const makeModuleAndBatteryPromises = () => {
  arrayOfObjects.map((obj) => {   

    createModules(obj.first).then((response) => {
      createBattery(response, obj.second).then(res => {
      assignAssets(res, obj.third).then(res => 'assignment done!');
      });
    });
  });
}
makeModuleAndBatteryPromises();
```

So looking at above code, it seems like i truly only have control over the first 3 API Calls in the 1st loop of arrayOfObjects. As i have `assignAssets(res).then(res => 'assignment done!');` which will allow me to do some operation like refresh page or redirect once the 3rd promise is resolved in the first loop.

However i need to do some operation on the 9th/final promise. Here is what i tried trying to make it async await.

```
     const makeModuleAndBatteryPromises = async () => {
    
      const promises = arrayOfObjects.map(async obj => {
        const firstResponse = await createModules(obj.first);
        const secondResponse = await createModules(firstResponse, obj.second); 
        await assignAssets(secondResponse);
      });
    
        await Promise.all(promises)
         .then(res => //do some action after all 9 promises resolved)
      }

        makeModuleAndBatteryPromises()
```

Not quite achieving what i was expecting it to, can some1 please tell me what i'm missing?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "not quite achieving", but If you expect some value from `assignAssets`, you'll need to change the mapping function to `return assignAssets(secondResponse)`.

Comment: Note: `obj.second` is only valid in the first iteration of `arrayOfObjects` ... that looks wrong for a start. What's also unclear is if all three iterations of arrayOfObjects should run in parallel or in series, and what results you need in `res` ... just the last promise of the last iteration? all results?

Comment: You forgot to pass `obj.third` to `assignAssets`, apart from that it looks ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you want the resolved value of the final assignAssets?

You've possibly confused yourself with a mix of `async`/`await` and `.then`

```
const makeModuleAndBatteryPromises = async() => {

    const promises = arrayOfObjects.map(async obj => {
        const firstResponse = await createModules(obj.first);
        const secondResponse = await createModules(firstResponse, obj.second);
        return assignAssets(secondResponse);
    });

    const res = await Promise.all(promises);
    const finalValue = res.at(-1); // or res[res.length-1];
    // do things with finalValue
}
makeModuleAndBatteryPromises()
```

Comment: Exactly what i was trying to get at. Thanks again @Bravo